# Python - lxml library 'clean' method erasing only half of empty <li> node

Tags: python, lxml, html-sanitizing, lxml.html

I'm using the lxml library in Python to clean html pages from potentially harmful code/parts I don't want. I noticed a strange behavior in the function: when given an empty `<li>` node, it removes the closing `</li>` tag but not the opening one.

For example,

```
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner
text = '<ul><li></li><li>FooBar</li></ul>'
cleaner = Cleaner()
print cleaner.clean_html(text)
```

will output `<ul><li><li>FooBar</li></ul>`...

As far as I can tell this only happens when dealing with `<li>`tags. Is that a bug from the lxml library? Am I doing something wrong?

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [closing tag for `<li>` in HTML is optional](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/index/elements.html), so its not a bug, though it may not be the behavior you desire.

You could force a closing tag by printing it as XML:

```
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner
import lxml.html as LH
text = '<ul><li></li><li>FooBar</li></ul>'
cleaner = Cleaner()
root = LH.fromstring(cleaner.clean_html(text, ))
print(LH.tostring(root, method='xml'))
```

yields

```
<ul><li/><li>FooBar</li></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I didn't know that the closing `li` tag was optional, but it is still weird that the function treats empty tags differently than the ones with content...
Thanks for your solution !